# How can I use the Team Foundation Server SCM plugin with a Jenkins Pipeline groovy script?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, tfs, jenkins-pipeline

Using Jenkins v2.46 and the 'Team Foundation Server Plug-in' v5.3.4, I have been able to get a Job scripted which will pull the latest source (.NET Core) from a repository in TFS (online) onto my Linux box and build a container, which is great!

As a next step towards a CI solution, I wanted to translate this job to a pipeline so I can script steps to push the generated container from a development environment to a QA environment. The first problem I have run into is that I have no idea how to tell Jenkins to pull from TFS online using the groovy syntax.

Using the groovy script generators, there is no option to script SCM control using the TFS plug-in, and I can't find any documentation to define how to do this.

Is it actually possible, or should I try to do something that kicks off a pipeline as a post-build step from my job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot more digging, it turns out that at the time of writing, it is not currently possible. See https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31803 for the open issue about this problem.

What I have done for now is created a GIT repository in TFS and am communicating with that; not as slick as the TFS plug-in for jobs, and can't seem to track changeset comments correctly, but it does trigger builds as I need them.

Answer (score 1):

steps {
              checkout([$class: 'TeamFoundationServerScm', localPath: 'D:\BUILD-Code-scm', projectPath: '$/ROOTDIR/Modules', serverUrl: 'http://XXX>XXX.com:8080/tfs/ROOTDIR', useOverwrite: true, useUpdate: true, userName: 'TLR\UNMAE', password: hudson.util.Secret.fromString('PASSWORD'), workspaceName: 'Hudson-${JOB_NAME}-${NODE_NAME}'])
           }

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you store your code in Visual Studio Team Services (TFS online) and want to use Jenkins for your continuous integration builds.

For the  CI , in TFS side you can directly trigger a Jenkins build when you push code to your team project's Git repository or when you check code in to Team Foundation version control.

If you are not able to use groovy script generators to script SCM control using the TFS plug-in. You can programmatically create a subscription that performs an action on an external (consumer) service when a specific event occurs in a TFS team project through using the [subscriptions REST APIs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/service-hooks/create-subscription).

For the details info, you could go through this tutorial: [Jenkins with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/jenkins)